# Shouldn't estimates from grouped data using weights be the same as the estimates from micro data

Tags: r, lm, weights

I was under the impression that weighted regression on grouped data, where the weights are equal to the number of group members, should result in the same estimates as running the regression on the micro data.  What am I doing wrong?

```r
library(dplyr)

micro <- lm(mpg~wt+hp, data=mtcars)
summary(micro)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ wt + hp, data = mtcars)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>    Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
#> -3.941 -1.600 -0.182  1.050  5.854 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept) 37.22727    1.59879  23.285  < 2e-16 ***
#> wt          -3.87783    0.63273  -6.129 1.12e-06 ***
#> hp          -0.03177    0.00903  -3.519  0.00145 ** 
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 2.593 on 29 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.8268, Adjusted R-squared:  0.8148 
#> F-statistic: 69.21 on 2 and 29 DF,  p-value: 9.109e-12

mtcars_grouped <- mtcars|>
  group_by(cyl, vs, am, gear, carb)|>
  summarise(mpg=mean(mpg),
            wt=mean(wt),
            hp=mean(hp),
            w=n())
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'cyl', 'vs', 'am', 'gear'. You can override
#> using the `.groups` argument.

grouped <- lm(mpg~wt+hp, weights=w, data=mtcars_grouped)
summary(grouped)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ wt + hp, data = mtcars_grouped, weights = w)
#> 
#> Weighted Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -3.1927 -1.6799 -0.5653  1.5473  4.0840 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept) 38.114910   1.575126  24.198 1.49e-11 ***
#> wt          -4.453825   0.681476  -6.536 2.79e-05 ***
#> hp          -0.025191   0.009134  -2.758   0.0173 *  
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 2.342 on 12 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.932,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.9207 
#> F-statistic: 82.22 on 2 and 12 DF,  p-value: 9.897e-08
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: When I ran your second block of code I got an error that it couldn't find %>% ,  What library is it in?

Comment: oops. magrittr... I should have used native pipe operator |>   ... fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You do loose information when you group data and replace individual values for dependent and independent variables by their group means. The estimates from the ungrouped and grouped data are still relatively close together, so the information loss was not really dramatic.

You would get the same *estimates* for regression coefficients as from the grouped data if you run the regression on data where you explicitly replace the variables by the group means as follows:

```r
library(dplyr)

mtcars_averaged <- mtcars |>
  group_by(cyl, vs, am, gear, carb) |>
  mutate(mpg = mean(mpg),
         wt  = mean(wt),
         hp  = mean(hp))
summary(lm(mpg ~ wt + hp, data = mtcars_averaged))

#> Call:
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ wt + hp, data = mtcars_averaged)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>    Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
#> -3.193 -1.016 -0.190  1.145  2.042 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept) 38.114910   1.013227  37.617  < 2e-16 ***
#> wt          -4.453825   0.438372 -10.160  4.6e-11 ***
#> hp          -0.025191   0.005876  -4.287 0.000182 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.507 on 29 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.932, Adjusted R-squared:  0.9273 
F-statistic: 198.7 on 2 and 29 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

**Note** however that estimates for residual error and standard errors have changed, together with the degrees of freedom. This is due to the fact that the model was fitted as if the data were independent, but in fact they are not, since they contain multiples of the same group average. Therefore you should use the approach from your question with grouped data instead.